# De repente aplicação começou a dar erro de "Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação que do nada passou a dar a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' ou
> uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um
> programa com um formato incorreto.

Detalhe, não foi feito nenhuma alteração no fonte.

Usamos a versão 1.0.66 do Sqlite, e gostaria de mantê-la se possível por conta de suas dependências.

Se eu instalar a versão mais recente do Sqlite no meu projeto ele ira atualizar outras dlls que ira afetuar o funcionamento da aplicação como um todo.

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Eu tentei instalar a versão recente do sqlite 1.0.117, mas ele atualizou a versão do EntitiyFramework gerando outros problemas.

Comment: já tentou limpara a `solution` ou apagar a pasta `obj` e recompilar?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: olha a arvore do git ou suas "changes", geralmente quando você coloca algum trecho de código e da um **alt+enter** esses erros podem acontecer por importação da dll errada

Segundo: outra coisa que pode ser feita, é entrar no csproj como o da imagem acima, e verificar se está corretamente referenciado a package.

exemplo do arquivo de packages: [csproj alterado apos alterar a package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9AVL.png)

Se puder mandar uma imagem do csproj e da packages para a gente te ajudar, seria importante

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).